# Radio button condition to set a value

Tags: jquery, html

I have 3 radio buttons[ 1Day, 1Week, 1Month ], initially 1day will be selected. I have all required starton and expireon values in hidden field.
Based on user selection I have to update starton and expireon values to span tag. here starton value same for all 3 selection, only expireon values will  be change based on radio button selection. Can any one help me here to complete this.

HTML code:

```
<body>
    <input type="hidden" id="startOn" value="01/01/2013" />
    <input type="hidden" id="expireDay" value="01/01/2013" />
    <input type="hidden" id="expireWeek" value="01/07/2013">
    <input type="hidden" id="expireMonth" value="01/31/2012" />
    <input type="radio" id="packageAmt1" name="packageAmt" checked="checked">1 Day</input>
    <input type="radio" id="packageAmt2" name="packageAmt">1 Week</input>
    <input type="radio" id="packageAmt3" name="packageAmt">1 Month</input>
    <br/>Start on<span id="startOnValue" /></span>
    <br/>Expire on<span id="expireOnValue" /></span>
</body>

jQuery Code:

$(document).ready(function () {
    var starton = $('#startOn').val()
    var expireday = $('#expireDay').val()
    var expireweek = $('#expireWeek').val()
    var expiremonth = $('#expireMonth').val()
    $('#startOnValue').text(starton);
    $('#expireOnValue').text(expireday);
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {

    });
});
```

Comment: Input tags don't work like that. `<label><input />text</label>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this

http://jsfiddle.net/sHHDF/

HTML

```
<input type="hidden" id="startOn" value="01/01/2013"/>
        <input type="hidden" id="expireDay" value="01/01/2013"/> 
        <input type="hidden" id="expireWeek" value="01/07/2013">
        <input type="hidden" id="expireMonth" value="01/31/2012"/>

        <input type="radio" id="packageAmt1" value="1"  name="packageAmt" checked="checked">1 Day</input>
        <input type="radio" id="packageAmt2" value="2" name="packageAmt">1 Week</input>
        <input type="radio" id="packageAmt3" value="3" name="packageAmt">1 Month</input><br/>

        Start on<span id="startOnValue" /></span><br/>
        Expire on<span id="expireOnValue" /></span>
```

jQuery

```
 var starton = $('#startOn').val()
            var expireday = $('#expireDay').val()
            var expireweek = $('#expireWeek').val()
            var expiremonth = $('#expireMonth').val()
            $('#startOnValue').text(starton);
            $('#expireOnValue').text(expireday);

        $('input[type=radio]').change(function()
        {
            var value_radio = $(this).val();

            if(value_radio == 1){

                $('#expireOnValue').html($('#expireDay').val());

            }
            if(value_radio == 2){

                $('#expireOnValue').html($('#expireWeek').val());

            }
            if(value_radio == 3){

                $('#expireOnValue').html($('#expireMonth').val());

            }

        });
```

Comment: But for better practice, can you do this without the if/else jungle?

Comment: I know but I poked you because it's always nice to write something then refine it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems you want to take the value from a hidden field and put it in the span depending on the radio selected.

Fist of all your input tag syntax is wrong. And add a value too for this to work.

```
<label><input type="radio" name="packageAmt" value="expireDay" checked="checked"/>1 Day</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="packageAmt" value="expireWeek"/>1 Week</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="packageAmt" value="expireMonth"/>1 Month</label>
```

and your span syntax is wrong

```
<br/>Start on <span id="startOnValue"></span>
<br/>Expire on <span id="expireOnValue"></span>
```

JQ

```
$('input[name="packageAmt"]').change(function(){

     // you could do in one line
     // $('#expireOnValue').text($('#' + $(this).val()).val());
     // but for easier reading...

     // get the value of the input whose ID is the VALUE of this radio
     var selector='#' + $(this).val();
     var text=$(selector).val();

     // put it in the span
     $('#expireOnValue').text(text);

}).first().trigger('change'); // trigger on page load to catch the default
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

You've done 99% of the work already. Inside the empty function body, use:

```
$('#expireOnValue').innetText = $('radio:checked')[0].innerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

With a little bit of HTML eiditing you can get it like this. Note that I added `data-` attribute to point to which input the select is responsible

**HTML**

```
<input type="hidden" id="startOn" value="01/01/2013" />
<input type="hidden" id="expireDay" value="01/01/2013" />
<input type="hidden" id="expireWeek" value="01/07/2013">
<input type="hidden" id="expireMonth" value="01/31/2013" />
<input type="radio" id="packageAmt1" data-expire='expireDay' name="packageAmt" checked="checked">1 Day</input>
<input type="radio" id="packageAmt2" data-expire='expireWeek'name="packageAmt">1 Week</input>
<input type="radio" id="packageAmt3" data-expire='expireMonth' name="packageAmt">1 Month</input>
<br/>Start on <span id="startOnValue"></span>

<br/>Expire on <span id="expireOnValue"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var starton = $('#startOn').val()
    var expireday = $('#expireDay').val()
    var expireweek = $('#expireWeek').val()
    var expiremonth = $('#expireMonth').val()
    $('#startOnValue').text(starton);
    $('#expireOnValue').text(expireday);

    $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
        var iid = $(this).data('expire');
        var date = $('#'+iid).val();
        $('#expireOnValue').text(date);
    });
});
```

FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/UxTWt/

Comment: I assume `expireMonth` value is a typo issue.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6LqY/)

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="startOn" value="01/01/2013"/>
<input type="hidden" id="expireDay" value="01/01/2013"/> 
<input type="hidden" id="expireWeek" value="01/07/2013">
<input type="hidden" id="expireMonth" value="01/31/2012"/>
<label for="packageAmt2">1 Day</label>
<input type="radio" id="packageAmt1" name="packageAmt" checked="checked" value="expireday" />
<label for="packageAmt2">1 Week</label>
<input type="radio" id="packageAmt2" name="packageAmt" value="expireweek" />
<label for="packageAmt2">1 Month</label>
<input type="radio" id="packageAmt3" name="packageAmt" value="expiremonth" />
<br/>
Start on <span id="startOnValue"></span><br/>
Expire on <span id="expireOnValue"></span>
```

JS:

```
var values = {
    starton: $('#startOn').val(),
    expireday: $('#expireDay').val(),
    expireweek: $('#expireWeek').val(),
    expiremonth: $('#expireMonth').val()
};
$('#startOnValue').text(values['starton']);
$('#expireOnValue').text(values['expireday']);
$('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
    $('#startOnValue').text(values['starton']);
    $('#expireOnValue').text(values[$(this).val()]);
});
```

Comment: Quick FYI, there's no need for a `for` if you just wrap the input with the label

Answer (score 0):

You have a markup issue on your span - closing the tag, then adding a closing tag. `/></span>`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#startOnValue').text($('#startOn').val());
    $('#expireOnValue').text($('#expireDay').val());
    $('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
        var i = $('input[type=radio]').index(this) + 1;
        $('#expireOnValue').text($('input[type=hidden]').eq(i).val())
    });
});
```

Comment: NOTE: IF you add any more hidden values, you would need to group them. likely with a class would be best, then select from that as otherwise the indexes would change.